# Why this "Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int."?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database containing two tables about CovidDeath and CovidVaccination. When I combined the two tables and tried to calculate the sum of the number of new vaccinations, there just comes the following error message:

*Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 77
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.*

```
SELECT dea.continent, dea.location, dea.date, dea.population, vac.new_vaccinations,
SUM(cast(vac.new_vaccinations as int)) OVER (Partition by dea.location ) AS RollingPeopleVaccinated
 FROM Portfolio_Covid_case..CovidDeaths  dea
 JOIN Portfolio_Covid_case..CovidVaccinations vac
   ON dea.location = vac.location
   AND dea.date = vac.date 
WHERE dea.continent IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY 2,3
```

Can somebody tell me what does this message exactly means and what might been gone wrong?

Comment: it sounds like you've got bad data. you should prevent people inputting bad data (using the correct data types might help), and decide what to do with the bad data when you encounter it. there's not really a technical question here that I can see?

Comment: Perhaps you have a many to many join, resulting in values much higher than you are expecting.

Comment: Side note, don't use `ORDER BY {Ordinal}` syntax; it can easily result in breaking changes: [Bad Habits to Kick : ORDER BY ordinal](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/06/bad-habits-to-kick-order-by-ordinal)

Comment: If a column should have numeric values only, its data type should not be varchar. And if it should not have numbers only, it is no colum one should sum. So, what you are trying does not make sense.

Comment: Are the numbers daily values or cumulative values?

Comment: Try the following 2 queries. What do they return?  `SELECT COUNT_BIG(*), SUM(CAST(new_vaccinations AS bigint)) FROM Portfolio_Covid_case..CovidVaccinations` and `SELECT COUNT_BIG(*) FROM Portfolio_Covid_case..CovidDeaths dea JOIN Portfolio_Covid_case..CovidVaccinations vac ON dea.location = vac.location AND dea.date = vac.date WHERE dea.continent IS NOT NULL`

Comment: Maximum value for INT is 2,147,483,647. Your sum probably goes larger than that. Number of vaccinated people in world is higher than that.

Comment: Number of Vaccinations in just China is bigger than that (people can have more than one vaccination)

Answer (score -2):

It means that vac.new_vaccinations contains data that SQL cannot convert into an INT.  Bad Data basically.  Look for strings or anything that doesn't look like a number.

Comment: I disagree. Any single non-numeric string value throws "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1234 Foo' to data type int." Any single numeric string value overflowing int throws "The conversion of the varchar value '3023456789' overflowed an int column." But if `SUM` overflows, it will throw "Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int." OP specifically reported the latter.